# tSQL select previous 3 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im not a sql person and have been thrust into being one :\

Im trying to get the previous 3 months of data without the current month.

```
WHERE DATEPART(m, start_date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -3, getdate())) 
 and DATEPART(yyyy, start_date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -3, getdate()))
```

this gets me the data from January only,  i need Jan-Mar.

```
WHERE start_date >= dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())-3,0)
```

and this gets me everything from jan 1st - now.

So now im stuck and not sure what to do.
mssql ver: 2012

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by previous 3 months. The previous 3 whole calendar months? The previous quarter? In May, will you expect Feb-April data?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the previous whole calendar months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE DateColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()) -3,0)
  AND DateColumn <  DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())   ,0)
```

This will return the data from  Between `2015-01-01` and `2015-03-31`

Comment: Why not `DateColumn < DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)`?  Aren't you just as vulnerable to the `BETWEEN` trap with `<= EOMONTH(...)`

Comment: `2015-03-31 12:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`Where datediff(mm, start_date, getdate()) in (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: This will hurt the performance as it will not make use of any indexes on the datetime column.

Comment: In fairness, the OP never mentioned anything about performance

Comment: true, but isnt that always a consideration :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps?:

```
WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -3, getdate()) AND DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())
```

Comment: [`What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Op didn't mention about date precision. So if start_date its like '20150401 00:00' should work.

Comment: If you read the article you would find out between operator does not work with dates it will miss out few rows. Read the article and you would know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
WHERE MONTH(start_date)>= MONTH(getdate())- 3 AND MONTH(start_date)< MONTH(getdate())
```

Comment: This will hurt the performance as it will not make use of any indexes on the datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a string and convert it to a date... such as:

```
WHERE start_date >= dateadd(month,-3, convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),Month(GETDATE())) + '/01/' + convert(varchar(10),Year(GETDATE()))))
    and start_date < convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),Month(GETDATE())) + '/01/' + convert(varchar(10),Year(GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE())),0)  -- FIRST DAY OF MONTH, THREE MONTHS AGO
      ,DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) -- LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH
```